# How to link a text box in Google Slides to a cell value in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-slides

I have a weekly Slides presentation that summaries result from Sheets. I don't want to have to edit the presentation every week, copying and pasting text from one webapp to another.

Since it is possible to insert a Chart and copy and paste a range from Google Sheets into Google Slides and maintain active link, **how can I also apply active link to a single text box if I only want one cell value**?

If this can be done then we can effectively separate the presentation from the underlying data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to merge data into slides**, is what I believe you are actually looking for.

> The overall steps are:
>
> 1. Create your presentation exactly as you want it to appear using dummy content to help you with the design.
> 2. For each content element that you'll be inserting, replace the dummy content with a tag. Tags are just text boxes or shapes with a
>      unique string.
> 3. In your code, use the Google Drive API to make a fresh copy of the presentation.
> 4. In your code, use the Slides API's `batchUpdate` method, with a set of `replaceAllText` requests, to perform all the text
>      substitutions throughout the presentation. Use
>      `replaceAllShapesWithImage` requests to perform image substitutions
>      throughout the presentation.
>
> When setting tags, make sure to use strings that are unlikely to occur
>   normally. For example, `{{account-holder-name}}` might be a good tag.
>
> Once you've created a deck with tags in it, be sure to make a copy and
>   use the Slides API to manipulate the copy. **Don't use the Slides API
>   to manipulate your master "template" copy!**

The above process is part of post involving quite a bit of coding and you can read about it, step by step under [Merging Data into Slides](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/merge)

There is also a video in YouTube ([Replacing text & images with the Google Slides API - The G Suite Dev Show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LSUbKZq4ZY)) accompanying the post.

Comment: This is quite a dirty way of doing it though, but no choice if this is the only option we have.